Automating Outlook Tasks under Sonoma using AppleScript
I am trying to automate some tasks in macOS Sonoma and Microsoft Outlook 16.78.3 using AppleScript.
This is my simple test script to check if I can access outlook items at all:
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theMessages to messages of inbox whose subject contains "email"
    if theMessages is not {} then
        set theMessage to item 1 of theMessages
        display dialog "Found at least one email with 'email' in the subject."
    else
        display dialog "No emails with 'email' in the subject."
    end if
end tell

The script runs without error, but i get the message: No emails with 'email' in the subject. which is not true as there are several test emails from me with the subject "email".
What steps can be followed to debug this or understand what’s missing to accomplish my automation?

Have you considered getting a debugger like https://latenightsw.com/. It might help you even with the free tier diagnose conditions that are hard to think through.

Thanks bmike, i will give it a go! This is my first experience working with Apple Script so i just use onboard tools for debugging.

I bet you will have an answer that helps others in short order. I’m glad you’re here and there are lots of excellent scripters, just sometimes an answer might take a month or longer to get posted. Also, Welcome to Ask Different.
